# Instantiate Start() runs after settings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Prefab that I `Instantiate`, but when I try to assign it a color, it doesn't work, and I think it is because I give it a random color in `Start()`, but What I would like to do is override that color but it isn't working.

I have a `Ball.cs` Start method that looks like this:

```
void Start(){
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    sr.color = Colors.colors[Random.Range(0, Colors.colors.Length)];
}
```

I then have in my `LevelController.cs` a method that balls in random locations on the screen, and it looks like this:

```
    int required = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < balls; i++){
        Vector3 screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0,Screen.width), Random.Range(0,Screen.height), Camera.main.farClipPlane/2));
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(ball, screenPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        // Color Reaction mode
        if(gameType == "Color Reaction"){
            obj.GetComponent<Ball>().gameType = "Color Reaction";
            // Make sure we have enough colors
            if(ballColor != null && i < required){
                Color bc = new Color(ballColor.r, ballColor.g, ballColor.b, 0.75f);
                obj.GetComponent<Ball>().ballColor = bc;
                obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = bc;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, when my ball gets created, I thought that it would create a random color as specified in `Ball.cs`, then it would assign a color with this:

```
obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = bc;
```

The thing is, is that it doesn't do that, it uses the color in `Ball.cs`. If I comment out the random color from `Ball.cs` it works. What do I need to do to get this to use the color in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Start` method on Ball.cs is called via reflection and is happening later on in the lifecycle than you're expecting (i.e it doesn't happen strait away after calling `GameObject.Instantiate`).

What I would recommend is that you create an `void Init()` method in Ball.cs and manually call this strait away after instantiating the new GameObject. If you don't want to go down that path that I would suggest creating a coroutine and calling `obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = bc;` at the end of the frame (using `WaitForEndOfFrame`), that way you'll execute your code after the `Start` method has been called.

Here are some docs (and a graph) on the Monobehaviour lifecycle:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

http://cfile4.uf.tistory.com/image/21416F4F525355A427B426

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: I did something like the `Init()` instead I did `SetColor()` and `SetColor(int Color)` So it then generates a random color then overrides it if needed.

Comment: Cool, it's the route that I'd go down - nice and simple.